# Route (docker) container traffic through IPSec

Tags: docker, strongswan

I have a ipsec (strongswan) connection to work, which in itself works fine, however traffic from containers doesn't seem to go through the ipsec tunnel. This is not expected from an end-user perspective since the ipsec isn't split tunnel.

```
#ipsec.conf
config setup

conn %default
  ikelifetime=28800s
  keylife=12h
  rekeymargin=3m
  keyingtries=1
  keyexchange=ikev1

conn worldstream
  ike = aes256-sha1-modp1024
  esp = aes256-sha1!
  xauth=client
  leftid=hbogert@acme.com
  leftauth=psk
  leftauth2=xauth
  leftsourceip=%config
  right=office.acme.com
  rightid=%any
  rightauth=psk
  auto=add
  rightsubnetwithin=0.0.0.0/0
```

I'm also using the [bypass-lan](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Bypass-lan) plugin from strongswan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to CAP_NET_ADMIN capability noted in [other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/567054/401231) I needed to add an iptables rule to SNAT the traffic from the Docker network to the desired VPN network.

```
iptables -j SNAT -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -o ${OUT_INTERFACE} -d ${VPN_NETWORK} -s ${DOCKER_NETWORK} --to-source ${VPN_HOST_IP}
```

I found that in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/810597/554856) to a similar question in ServerFault:

Comment: This works, however, if you create docker networks after the command given above, then those docker networks are again *not* routed through the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

It should work by giving the container the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability (see [Running strongSwan on a cloud platform](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Cloudplatforms)).

This means using the `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` flag with docker or `cap_add: - NET_ADMIN` with docker-compose.

This assumes strongswan has this capability as well (it seems to have it by default).

Comment: I think this is only needed if your vpn process is containerized as well, which is not the case in my, the OP's, case.